# How do I set basic options with meson?

Tags: command-line, command-line-arguments, meson-build, buildconfiguration

I'm trying to configure a project with meson. Specifically, I'm trying to set some of the options.

`meson config` tells me, among other things:

```
Core options:
  Option          Current Value Possible Values                                          Description                                             
  ------          ------------- ---------------                                          -----------                                             
  buildtype       debug         [plain, debug, debugoptimized, release, minsize, custom] Build type to use                                       

Base options:
  Option      Current Value Possible Values                                               Description                                   
  ------      ------------- ---------------                                               -----------                                   
  b_lto       false         [true, false]                                                 Use link time optimization
```

(other options were clipped from this printout of course.)

So, I write:

```
meson build . --buildtype=release
```

in my build directory, and this goes fine - no warnings or errors (I double-checked that the option value had changed). Then I write:

```
meson build . --b_lto=true
```

but this gets me:

```
meson: error: unrecognized arguments: --b_lto=true
```

I also tried `-b_lto=true`, `--b_lto true`, `b_lto=true` and `b_lto true`. And all of those without the `true` value. No luck.

How do I set these "base options" then?

Comment: @blubase: Can you post a link to that issue please? Also, make that an answer?

Comment: The meson team informed me, that actually, the `--option=value` and `--option value` style passing of arguments only applies to the information in the `universal options` but not the other group of objects, the manual was not explicit in this regard. I'll change my answer (again) to reflect his information.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `--option=value`, and `--option value` styles to pass arguments only applies to the *universial options* section in [meson's manual](https://mesonbuild.com/Builtin-options.html)...so not to *base options*, and others. Instead use the `-Doption=value` syntax to set options. It is the suggested way, since `meson setup --help` declares `[-D option]` to be used for setting all sorts of options. See this [answer](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/7633#issuecomment-679087184) by the meson team. So, in your case run:

```
meson build . -Db_lto=true
```

or

```
meson configure build -Db_lto=true
```

If the build directory changed since the last configure use `reconfigure` instead.

```
meson reconfigure build -Db_lto=true
```

or explicitly:

```
meson setup --reconfigure -Db_lto=true build
```

Comment: Why `reconfigure` rather than `configure`?

Comment: `reconfigure` is used to change an already existing build dir. `meson configure` just shows the current setup, as far as i understand.

Comment: Ok, i reread that part of the manual. Actually, in many cases `configure` and `reconfigure` do the same. Only if new options have been introduced since the last configure, just `meson configure build -D option=value` might not allow to set this new option, `reconfigure`, and explicitly `meson setup --reconfigure` do.

Comment: "better use this ordering, since its specified this way in the manual" -> Actually this ordering will lead to ```WARNING: Running the setup command as `meson [options]` instead of `meson setup [options]` is ambiguous and deprecated.```